# using a variable in xml parsing and it doesn't work

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

could anyone please help me. 
My problem is that I am using a variable to identify an element section of the many galleries I have under the tag "galleryType" and nothing is returning for me to display. 
Am I searching for my galleryType the right way in my code or do I need to loop through my galleryTypes on my XML. thanks in advance.

here is my xml code:

```
<My_gallery>
    <galleryType Name="GalleryName001">
        <images>
            <image label="example text" thumb_src="folder/thumb001.jpg">folder/image001.jpg</image>
            <image label="example text" thumb_src="folder/thumb002.jpg">folder/image002.jpg</image>
            <image label="example text" thumb_src="folder/thumb003.jpg">folder/image003.jpg</image>
        </images>
    </galleryType>
    <galleryType Name="GalleryName002">
        <images>
            <image label="example text" thumb_src="folder/thumb001.jpg">folder/image001.jpg</image>
            <image label="example text" thumb_src="folder/thumb002.jpg">folder/image002.jpg</image>
            <image label="example text" thumb_src="folder/thumb003.jpg">folder/image003.jpg</image>
        </images>
    </galleryType>
</My_gallery>
```

Here is my as3 code:

```
public function selectGallery(val:String):void {
    galleryName = val;
    navClass = new navigationClass(galleryName);
    galleryName = navClass.getGalleryType;
    loadXML("myGallery001.xml");
}

private function loadXML(img_source:String):void {
    xmlData = new XML();
    xmlData.ignoreWhitespace = true;
    xmlLoader = new URLLoader();
    xmlLoader.load(new URLRequest(img_source));
    xmlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, XMLloaded);
}

private function XMLloaded(evt:Event):void {
    xmlData = new XML(evt.target.data);     

    // I am getting a result back with my trace but nothing is going into my imgList
    imgList = xmlData.galleryType.(@Name==galleryName).images.*;
    trace(xmlData.galleryType.(@Name == galleryName).images.*);
}images
```

Comment: Are you sure of the value contain into galleryName, into evt.target.data ?

Comment: evt.target.data holds only my XML. galleryName is a public variable, is this what your mean?

Comment: Can you trace what is the content of galleryName and evt.target.data when into XMLloaded

Comment: thanks for the reply. I am sorry I couldn't back to you earlier. Yes my traces on galleryName returns the gallery name for the specific elements I am trying to pull from my xml, and a trace on evt.target.data returns my xml doc. I don't get why my variable is not recognized when I try to assign the gallery type and it's sub-nodes to the imgList XMLList class object.

Comment: what is `imgList` data type, where is it declared and is it created/initialized?

Comment: imgList is a XMLList class object. It is declared publicly but has not been assigned as a XMLList class object. um I am really having trouble with my variable not working in a that statement but it shows me the right result in my trace. :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `imgList = new XMLList(new XML(xmlData.galleryType.(@Name == galleryName).images.* as String));`

Answer (score 0):

I would go for looping, that way you have more control over the values that passes in the loop.

example:

```
var thumbArray = new Array();

function processXML(evt:Event):void
{
     galleryXML = new XML(evt.target.data);
     for each (var i:XML in galleryXML.files.file)
     {
          thumbArray.push(i.thumbnail);
     }
}
```

then you can bind the Array to your List or DataGrid, also changing an Array to reflect changes in your List or other object is easier to control, if made [Bindable] it will reflect changes to the array to the Object onto which it is connected.

Comment: wilfred thanks for the reply. I am not sure what you mean in your code example. Even if I push all my nodes (which is my gallery type) and subnodes to an array call thumbArray, I still wouldn't be able to reach my subnodes of the gallery types I want.

Comment: well the example was purely meant as an example to loop through an XML object, if you need more levels i would suggest using an ArrayCollection and filling them up with Array's. Then you can reach all subnodes as well. I was merely pointing you in a direction to decide between your way described in your question, and using a loop. You can find info on ArrayCollection here: [link](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/collections/ArrayCollection.html).

Comment: Hey Wilfred. Thanks for the comment. I haven't read much on ArrayCollection but it does should like the right track from here. I misunderstood how I could use your example that would filter out the right node and it's subnodes before but I will be using that formula. thanks